# Python Selenium with Proxy is unpredictable

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I have been working on a web scraper, it works fine without proxy, but on some website I need a proxy to avoid getting an Access Denied.
The problem is that the proxy is far away from me and the page gets loaded very slowly, it takes around from 80 to 100 seconds to fully load and most of the time it just fails, like if the page is getting renderer partially or just wrong.
I'm not sure whats the problem but it seems pretty unpredictable because sometime an item is being scrapped and sometime not..

Can the slowness of the page loading cause this or there is another problem which I'm not aware of? Without proxy everything is fine and the code is the same.

PS: I'm using the Chrome Driver

Comment: It is too general to tell. But given you mentioned proxy and slow rendering time. It is possible the page is not fully loaded, causing missing elements, especially if you have not setup proper conditional wait like ```implicitly_wait``` or ```WebDriverWait``` coupled with some of the ```expected_conditions```  likes ```presence_of_element_located``` , ```visibility_of_element_located```

Comment: @Frederickcjo thanks for your answer! Yeah I dont know myself either because, isnt selenium supposed to wait for the page to be fully loaded since the page strategy by default is Normal?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Most webpage has different components load at different time intervals even when the page has been loaded. Hence, missing elements issue and why you should do some implicit or explicit wait. You can read up more about it [via the official documentations](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)